# find the value of $\int_{0}^{1} \max\{ x,\frac{1}{2}-x\}\,\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration

---

find the value of    $\int_{0}^{1} \max\mspace{-4mu}\big\{ x,\frac{1}{2}-x\big\}\,\mathrm{d}x$?

I was trying this question many times. but I could not able to solve it, firstly I was take max value, I was taking $x=0$, then i got $\frac{1}{2}$ and for  $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{2} \,\mathrm{d}x$, I got the value $\frac{1}{2}$ .But I'm still  doubting about my answer because i take the value at $x=0$. other value I have not been taken..

If anybody help me i would be very thankful to him....

Comment: So take the value at the other points. The answer  requires that you simplify the expression $\max(x , \frac 12 -  x)$. Do this for all $x$, and then break up $[0,1]$ into subsets for which this answer is similar.

Comment: im not getiing@астон вілла олоф мэллбэрг

Comment: You can look at the answers below for clarification. In the second answer, the answerer has simplified the integrand. You can ask him how.

Answer (score 1):

For $x \in [0,1]$ we have

$\max\{x, 1/2-x\}=1/2-x$ if $0 \le x \le 1/4$ and $\max\{x, 1/2-x\}=x$ if $1/4 \le x \le 1$.

Comment: thanks @ fred ...but why u not take 0≤ x≤ 1/2?

Comment: We have $\frac{1}{2}-x \le x \iff x \ge \frac{1}{4}$. It follows: $\frac{1}{2}-x \ge x \iff x \le \frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: thanks @ FRED  now i got it...

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\int\limits_{0}^{1} \max\mspace{-4mu}\Big\{x,\frac{1}{2}-x\Big\}\,\mathrm{d}x = \int\limits_{0}^{\frac{1}{4}} \Big( \frac{1}{2}-x\Big)\,\mathrm{d}x + \int\limits_{\frac{1}{4}}^{1} x\,\mathrm{d}x = \frac{9}{16}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Let us find in which parts of the domain where either argument of the $\max$ dominates, and integrate separately.

We need to solve the inequation

$$x\ge\frac12-x,$$ the solution of which is

$$x\ge\frac14.$$

Hence,

$$\int_0^1\max\left\{x,\frac12-x\right\}dx=\int_{1/4}^1x\,dx+\int_0^{1/4}\left(\frac12-x\right)dx.$$

---

For the least effort, we can transform the second integral by a change of variable and get

$$\int_{1/4}^1x\,dx-\int_{1/2}^{1/4}x\,dx=\frac12\left(1-\frac1{16}-\frac1{16}+\frac14\right).$$

Comment: thanks @YvesDaoust

Answer (score 0):

**Using tricks:**

You can pull a term out of a $\max$ expression.

$$\max\left(x,\frac12-x\right)=x+\max\left(0,\frac12-2x\right).$$

Then obviously, the integral is that of $x$ over the whole range, $1\cdot\dfrac{0+1}2$, and the integral of $\dfrac12-2x$ where this expression is positive, i.e. in $\left[0,\dfrac14\right]$, giving $\dfrac14\dfrac{\dfrac12+0}2$.

Total $\dfrac9{16}$.

[To quickly compute the integrals of linear functions, multiply the interval length by the average of the values at endpoints.]

Answer (score 0):

What is the area of the shaded region?

[image]

It can be decomposed as the union of $9$ squares with side length $\frac{1}{4}$, hence the answer is $\color{blue}{\frac{9}{16}}$.
Can you figure out why it equals $\int_{0}^{1}\max\left\{x,\tfrac{1}{2}-x\right\}\,dx$ ?

Comment: very nice explaination,,,thanks @ jack  D aurizio